# Zero-truncated Sichel distribution in R

Tags: r, distributions, count-data, gamlss

I'm trying to fit the GAMLSS library's Sichel distribution to some zero-truncated data, but the only way to get the function to work is to include the zero-class anyway but give it a frequency of 0, which doesn't take into account the zero-truncated nature of my data. Can anyone suggest a way to properly "redistribute" the zero-class's probability to the remaining probabilities (or some other, better, course of action using Sichel)?

If you run the following example, you'll see that `sum(pdf2)` equals 1, but that the zero class that has a probability in my case of 0 is still allocated around 27% of the cum probability:

```
Counts = data.frame(n = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                    freq = c(0,182479,76986,44859,24315,49,100,490,106,0,2))

gamlss(n~1,family=SICHEL, control=gamlss.control(n.cyc=50),data=Counts )

pdf2 = dSICHEL(x=with(Counts, n), mu = 1.610, sigma = 98.43, nu = 3.315)

print( with(Counts, cbind(n, freq, fitted=pdf2*sum(freq))), dig=9)

sum(pdf2)
```

Answer (score 2):

In R, load the package `gamlss.tr` (for fitting truncated distributions), then:

```
y<-rSICHELtr(1000,2,0.5,-1)
hist(y)
gen.trun(par=0,family="SICHEL", type="left",delta=0.0001)
m1<-gamlss(y~1,family=SICHELtr)
summary(m1)
```

The above code generates a sample of 1000 from the truncated SICHEL distribution,
then fits it.  Note in the simulation `mu=2`, `sigma=0.5` and `nu=-1`.

In the summary fitted model gives fitted `log(mu)`, `log(sigma)` and `nu`.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Robert. We prefer if you don't sign your posts; note that your avatar & username (w/ a link to your userpage) are added automatically to your posts. Since you're new here, you'll want to read our [about page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/about) & our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq), which contain info like this about CV.

Answer (score 1):

By zero-truncated, do you mean that any data that would have had a 0 as a response is just missing? In that case, can't you just put the 0s in?

Or do you mean that some proportion of the time, instead of getting a sensical answer, you get a 0 instead? That sounds like zero-inflation to me. In that case, there are zero-inflated poisson and similar in GAMLSS.

I don't know of a zero-inflated Sichel, and there's nothing in GAMLSS for it, but is there a particularly good reason for using the Sichel distribution for your data? Does it reflect the underlying process particularly well? (I believe that the Sichel represents a mixture model of Poissons, where the meta-distribution is distributed as Inverse Gaussian...)

Comment: Follow-up: 1. The SICHEL() function is in the gamlss.dist package. 2. Would a simple (and correct!) method to adjust the > 0 probabilities be to divide them by (1-.27)? --Jeff

Comment: By zero-truncated, I mean that the probability of a zero-count is zero. My data are the count of items purchased _per transaction_ at a convenience store over a five-day period--obviously there's at least one item being bought per purchase (but usually fewer than, say, 20). The schema looks something like: DATE, TRANSACTION_ID, COUNT_OF_PURCHASES As to Sichel, I do have reason to believe that that distribution might provide a good fit, but I'm trying several others as well (e.g., ZTNB). Thanks for your reply. --Jeff

Comment: Oh, I see. ZTNB seems viable. Or you could model visits *including* unobserved non-purchases, as you originally noted. That would basically be a free parameter, but if Sichel is describing some other aspect of the underlying behavior, it might be worth it.

Comment: Incidentally, you should have responded to my answer, not in a separate answer. And if you like the answer, please up-vote it, and if it actually answers the question to your satisfaction, accept it. (Likewise, your follow-up should have been a comment on your question, not an answer.) Welcome to Stack Exchange! :)

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of the zero truncated law is 
$$ \mathbb P(X = k | X > 0) = { \mathbb P(X = k) \over 1 - \mathbb P(X=0) },$$
for $k>0$.

So in R it is given by `dSICHEL( x, mu, sigma, nu)/(1-dSICHEL(0, mu, sigma, nu))` and its log by `dSICHEL( x, mu, sigma, nu, log=TRUE)-log(1-dSICHEL(0, mu, sigma,nu))`... it is then easy to compute the log-likelihood for given parameters $\mu, \sigma, \nu$. You could try to maximize it using `nlm` or `optim`.